# How to solve $x^x=8$ and prove that it has one and only one irrational root

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

> $x^x=8$

We must find the only one irrational solution, and prove that this solution is the only one.
The uniqueness of the root seems obvious to me from the monotonically increasing graph of the $x^x$, but I don't know how to solve.
I've tried messing around with logarithms, but it didn't work. So far my best guess was to note that

$2,3884^{2,3884}=7,99964856151$

and try to find an expression involving roots of naturals that would be close to $2,3884$, but there are way too many numbers.

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure you are being asked to find an exact solution? there is not one in terms of "elementary functions"

Comment: To prove there exists a solution and it's unique, appealing to the monotonically increasing graph, like you mentioned, seems like a great idea!

Comment: @hunter Yes, we were asked to find an exact solution. (Though our Calculus prof. might be just messing with us, the dewey-eyed freshmen.)

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A173162 for more digits.

Comment: Well, there is *sort of* an exact solution. Let $W(x)$ be the 'Lambert W' function (aka product log). Then $x = \frac{\ln 8}{W(\ln 8)}$.

Comment: You may try to consider $e^{x \log x} = e^{\log 8}$

Comment: I believe anything to do with functions that cannot be expressed explicitly are best solved using the Lambert W function $W(x)$

Comment: In terms of the uniqueness of the solution, if you take $\log$ of both sides you reach the equation $\log x=\frac{\log 8}{x}$; the solution is the intersection point of one increasing and one decreasing function so it has to be unique. In case this could qualify for a uniqueness proof.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Irrationality of the root:** If it was rational, say $\frac{a}{b}$ (both $a$ and $b$ positive natural numbers), we would have

$$\left( \frac{a}{b} \right ) ^{\frac{a}{b}} = 8$$

$$\left( \frac{a}{b} \right )^a = 8^b$$

But this would mean that a positive natural power of the rational number $\frac{a}{b}$ is a natural number, so it must be a natural number too, so $b=1$. But this leads to the contradiction

$$a^a = 8$$

Only thing $a$ can be is $1, 2, 4, 8$ (because $8$ doesn't have any other positive divisors) but none of these work.